# Get lines formatted with a specific date or later

Tags: sed, date

I am looking at logs files that have timestamps and I just want the entries from a specific time period and after.

```
2018-06-17T13:43:09
```

For example I want all entries from 18:00:00 on 2018-06-23 and onward.

```
sed -n '2018/-06/-23T18,$p' board3
sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unknown command: `/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -n '/2018-06-23T\(1[89]\|2\)/p' board3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string comparison here:

```
awk '$0 > "2018-06-23T18"' < file
```